# Can I get from a transaction to contract state changes using RPC API

Tags: transactions, contract-design, json-rpc

If I'm talking to geth using the JSON RPC API, I've found a transaction I'm interested in and I can see that it is calling a contract (data in the 'input' part of the transaction object.)

Can I then figure out what changes to balances are as a result of this invocation? I don't see anything on the TransactionReceipt object.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking about **balances** and have the transaction using JSON-RPC, you can see the `from`, `to`, and `value` of the transaction.  You can make a simple **guess** that `from`'s balance has decreased by `value`, and `to`'s balance has increased by `value`.

It's a simple guess because you cannot know if the `to` contract sent the `value` to other accounts (including some back to `from`), unless you look more -- some examples: look at the code of the contract to see what it does, run the code through the Ethereum Virtual Machine or a simulator, or compare the differences between the current and previous block.

Comment: that won't show you the gas cost if one of the parties is the one that submitted the transaction.  Also, in general guessing from delta numbers in distributed systems is fraught with peril.  Should always use absolute counters whenever possible.  Restating the original question:  can we see the balance of an address at a particular transaction?

Comment: @PaulS.  Agree with your points; your question is certainly clearer and I'm not sure if that's what the question intended.  Maybe it is and I think it's fine to write your answer as you perceive the question.

Comment: You also could just log an event in your transaction and get the balance of whatever address you wish (address.balance in solidity).   Those logs are in the receipt I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but what specifically is not clear about my question? I know how to derive changes in balance based on the 'value' / 'gasUse' / 'gasPrice' fields from the Transaction and TransactionReceipt objects. But there can be other side effects; not just to the from or to accounts from the code in the contract itself - I'm wondering if these are exposed via JSON RPC. I don't really want to start trying to start running my own EVM to do this. But perhaps that is indeed the only way?

Comment: If you have more than one address call your contract's API per block you might have a hard time deciphering which transaction charged which balance...

Comment: It's not my contract - it could be any contract that I know nothing about. I'm just trying to find out what changes to balances might have occurred as a result of the call. It sounds to me like it can't be done at the moment.

Comment: There's now debug & trace methods that do this https://docs.chainstack.com/reference/ethereum-debug-trace-rpc-methods